# Faster way to query a value if present among multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new dataframe from an existing one (kinda slicing) which will contain those rows which satisfy the condition among multiple columns. Currently I write each columns names separately in the query

`df1=df[(df.Q25_1 == 'Earpods') & (df.Q25_2 == "Earpods") & (df.Q25_3 == "Earpods") ......... & (df.Q25_20 == "Earpods")]`

Is there a easier way to compare them like slicing techniques eg. `df[(df[Q25_1:Q25_20)]`

Comment: Are you sure you want to get rows where all columns equal 'Earpods'? Or at least one satisfies the condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `filter`:

```
df[df.filter(like='Q25_').eq('Earpods').all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried with filter but had missed the `.any()` part

Comment: `any` or `all` it depends on what you want to get.

Answer (score 2):

If the columns are contiguous [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) supports label based slicing which is similar to the intuition of `df[(df[Q25_1:Q25_20)]`:

```
df[df.loc[:, 'Q25_1':'Q25_20'].eq('Earpods').all(axis=1)]
```

[`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) is needed to check that *all* values in the row (`axis=1`) are `True` (match the condition of equal to 'Earpods'. (compound `&` statements)

[`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) can be used to check if *any* value in the row is `True` (compound `|` statements)

---

Sample Program:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Sample': 1,
                   'Q25_1': ['Earpods', 'Something Else', 'Not Here'],
                   'Q25_2': ['Earpods', 'Not Earpods', 'Also Not Here'],
                   'Q25_3': ['Earpods', 'Earpods', 'Nothing'],
                   'Test': 2})
print(df)
print('# All')
print(df[df.loc[:, 'Q25_1':'Q25_3'].eq('Earpods').all(axis=1)])
print('# Any')
print(df[df.loc[:, 'Q25_1':'Q25_3'].eq('Earpods').any(axis=1)])
```

```
   Sample           Q25_1          Q25_2    Q25_3  Test
0       1         Earpods        Earpods  Earpods     2
1       1  Something Else    Not Earpods  Earpods     2
2       1        Not Here  Also Not Here  Nothing     2
# All
   Sample    Q25_1    Q25_2    Q25_3  Test
0       1  Earpods  Earpods  Earpods     2
# Any
   Sample           Q25_1        Q25_2    Q25_3  Test
0       1         Earpods      Earpods  Earpods     2
1       1  Something Else  Not Earpods  Earpods     2
```

Comment: Tomorrow 25k 